# Cannot boot my dual booted pc

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual booted pc.
I tried to uninstall Linux by deleting the partition.

When I boot my pc, there is an error as shown in the attached picture:

[image: this]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? have you tried using a earlier kernel

Comment: That is what usually happens if you just delete the Ubuntu partition. If Windows is installed in UEFI-mode, change the boot-order in UEFI-settings.

Comment: If a BIOS/MBR install you have to restore the "other" systems boot loader before you delete the Linux partition. Grub in MBR relies on rest of grub in Ubuntu install. BIOS/MBR: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader  IF UEFI you can also edit out the UEFI entries for Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me because of the UEFI installation. I solved it with reinstalling Linux with deleting it's partition and creating another one to install it with forcing the UEFI installation.

[If  you had encountered  this message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT56E.jpg)   while installing you can try this method I wrote down below.

Firstly, you need a bootable - Linux installed USB drive.(I'm assuming you have it.) 
Then after booting your PC you need to install GParted from : http://gparted.org/download.php (select the correct Linux Distribution)

After that, you can delete the partition you used to install Linux. Then reboot your PC and install Linux again with forcing the UEFI installation.